# C how to increment a pointer by specified value

Tags: c, pointers

I want to increment a pointer by a specific number: 400h (1024 in decimal). I want it to point to a memory that starts at 0x400 above the base address and write 0x003ffff to this address.

The pointed-to type is `uint32_t`, so it occupies 4 bytes. Does this mean that, to have the pointer point to memory that is located precisely 0x400 higher, I need to increment it 1024/4 = 256 times?

This would result in the code:

```
#define BASE_PTR             (0xFC014000u)
uint32_t* register_ptr;
register_ptr = BASE_PTR + 256;
*register_ptr = 0x003ffff;
```

It seems wrong, and is also not really clear. Is there another way of achieving the same goal? I was thinking about:

```
(*(uint32_t *)(BASE_PTR + 0x400)) = 0x003ffff;
```

However, I am not certain if the 1024 in the code above evaluates to 1024, or 1024*4, as `sizeof(uint32_t)` is 4....

I would be very grateful for any hints or tips!

Comment: Why don't you print the value of `register_ptr` and check?

Comment: `BASE_PTR` is just a number in your code, so normal arithmetic rules apply. Note that `(*(uint32_t *)(BASE_PTR + 0x400))` is the same location as `(*((uint32_t*)BASE_PTR + 0x100))`. The first one adds two integers and converts the result to a pointer. The second one converts an integer to a pointer and adds an integer to it (so the amount added is scaled up by the size of the type pointed to).

Comment: You would have to cast, or define, the BASE_PTR to be a (char *) (or a uintptr!) if you want byte oriented pointer addition.  You could then cast it to a uint32 * after the addition.  Note: be careful of pointer aliasing; don't use the byte pointer and word pointer at the same time.

Comment: Note, your edit chanegd the meaning of the question quite a bit.

Comment: sorry for the edit! I just overlooked this one pointer in my original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both your code snippets, the `BASE_PTR` constant is an `unsigned int`; so, the expressions `BASE_PTR + 256` and `BASE_PTR + 0x400` are performed as (unsigned) *integer* arithmetic (not as *pointer* arithmetic), so there is no 'compensation' applied for the size of any object referenced by a pointer to which you subsequently assign the result. However, if you first assign (or cast) the `BASE_PTR` value to a `uint32_t*` pointer, then add something to that, the addend *will* then be multiplied (inherently) by the size of the pointed-to object.

So, the following first two lines inside the `main` function in the following snippet are equivalent:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define BASE_PTR             (0xFC014000u)

int main()
{
    uint32_t* p1 = (uint32_t*)(BASE_PTR + 0x400); // Simple unsigned integer arithmetic
    uint32_t* p2 = (uint32_t*)(BASE_PTR) + 0x100; // Pointer arithmetic: uses pointee size
    printf("%p %p\n", (void*)p1, (void*)p2);
    return 0;
}
```

However, changing your definition of `BASE_PTR` to cast it as a `uint32_t*` pointer:

```c
#define BASE_PTR             (uint32_t*)(0xFC014000u)
```

changes things significantly; *any* addition on that (without other casts) will then be performed as pointer arithmetic, and the size of the pointed-to object will be applied.

Comment: OP changed their code snippet (by adding a cast to the #DEFINE) and invalidated this answer.

Comment: Also this answer is incorrect. You need to change the first addition to remove the `uint32_t*` cast

Comment: @AdrianMole My bad. Your answer is indeed correct. I missed the bracket.